# Azure DevOps Build with Parameters

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible in azure-pipelines.yml to define multi-value at runtime parameters so when you run the build you have to input so values

```
parameters:
  - name: image
    displayName: Pool Image
    type: string
    default: ubuntu-latest
    values:
    - windows-latest
    - vs2017-win2016
    - ubuntu-latest
```

Upon clicking Run in Azure DevOps you are presented with a dropdown and you select which option you require ???

Upon your selection, the build will only run certain steps or tasks based on your selection

Comment: Hi Dropdown parameters is not yet supported in azure devops pipeline. Did you try out below workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropdown parameters is not yet supported on azure devops pipeline.

There is a workaround that you can create a variable with all the possible values, and enable **Settable at queue time**. The detailed steps are in below:

**Edit** your yaml pipeline, Click the **3dots** on the top right corer and choose **Triggers**

[image]

Go to **Variables** tab, create a variable and check **Settable at queue time**

[image]

Then when you queue your pipeline, you will be allowed to set the value for this variable.

[image]

> After you setup above steps. You also need to add condtions for your tasks.

For below example the script task can only run when the Environment variable is equal to prod and previous steps are all succeeded.

```
steps:
  - script: echo "run this step when Environment is prod"
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Environment'], 'prod'))
```

Please check here for more information about [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)

You can also [submit a feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) (Click suggest a feature and choose Azure devops)to Microsoft Develop, hope they will consider implementing this feature in the future.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure when it was added, but drop down parameters are now available:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: env
    displayName: Environment
    type: string
    values:
      - dev
      - prod
      - test
      - train
    default: train
```

will provide me with a drop down of `dev`, `prod`, etc., prepopulated with the value `train`.

Moreover, it will be a drop down if 4 values or more, and a radio dial with 3 or less.  For instance,

```yaml
  - name: department
    displayName: Business Department
    type: string
    values:
      - AI
      - BI
      - Marketing
    default: AI
```

will create a radio dial with `AI` selected by default.  Note that the YAML is identical between the two, with the exception of 4 values in the first and 3 in the second.